# How are you supposed to use the `min_itemsize` parameter of `HDFStore.append`?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I want to cap the size of a string column in an HDF store. You are supposed to do this with `min_itemsize`. The documentation states:

> **min_itemsize**
>
> The underlying implementation of HDFStore uses a fixed column width
>   (itemsize) for string columns. A string column itemsize is calculated
>   as the maximum of the length of data (for that column) that is passed
>   to the HDFStore, in the first append. Subsequent appends, may
>   introduce a string for a column larger than the column can hold, an
>   Exception will be raised (otherwise you could have a silent truncation
>   of these columns, leading to loss of information). In the future we
>   may relax this and allow a user-specified truncation to occur.
>
> Pass min_itemsize on the first table creation to a-priori specify the
>   minimum length of a particular string column. min_itemsize can be an
>   integer, or a dict mapping a column name to an integer. You

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#string-columns

Ok, so when I do this, I get an unexpected result. I set `min_itemsize` to 1 here. This should set all string columns to 1 character strings. But that is not the case. Why? What am I misunderstanding about the documentation?

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5', mode='w', format='table', complevel=9,
                    complib='blosc:lz4')

values = [['a', 'b'], ['aa', 'bb'], ['aaa', 'bbb']]
columns = ['A', 'B'] 
data = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns)

store.append('df', data, min_itemsize=1)

print(store.df)
store.close()

     A    B
0    a    b
1   aa   bb
2  aaa  bbb
```

I was expecting the exception mentioned din the documentation to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the size of the column will be set to the largest value appended in the first DataFrame or `max_itemsize`, whichever is greater. The [pytables.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/pytables.py) code has some references to that logic:

```
itemsize = max(1, libwriters.max_len_string_array(ensured))

itemsize = max(min_itemsize or 0, itemsize)

if min_itemsize is not None and self.typ.itemsize < min_itemsize:
```

Comment: Hmm, what does that mean for `min_itemsize` now? How can I cap the column's string length?

Comment: If the initial data could exceed the desired limit, perhaps initialize the data store with an empty table and min_itemsize first before appending the actual data.

Comment: You mean like this?: `store.append('df', pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B']), min_itemsize=1)`
`store.append('df', data, min_itemsize=1)` 

Does not work either.

Comment: Perhaps insert a row of dummy data with min_itemsize to initialize the table. That row can be later removed.